# How do I count the total number of iterations within a loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I'm running a basic user photos system on a Ruby on Rails app.  I want to count the total number of photos a user has. Can I do that with a Ruby method for counting the total number of iterations through a loop??

```
@photos.each do |photo| 
   photo.total_number_of_iterations
end
```

Comment: and also show us the associations you have..between user and photo

Comment: No...it's a table in the database that has many attributes.

Comment: @Andre Deineko...yea...that's what I thought would be the easy answer, but it throws a "no method .count" error on the page.

Comment: if user `has_many :photos` and photo `belongs_to :user` then `user.photos.count` should work

Comment: so is it the case? do the associations established as I assumed?

Comment: It would be very convenient to get the count like that, for example when working with the percent value of the iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User has many photos

```
@user.photos.count #as user has_many photos
```

From loop with index of each photo object

```
@user.photos.map.with_index.to_a

  #[[photo1, 0], [photo2, 1]]
```

To get total count/ or total iteration of photos

```
@user.photos.map.with_index(1).to_a.last.last
```

You can find [enumerator#with_index](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to iterate each photo?

```
@photos.count
```

gives you the number of photos.